# Get string Base64 from input type:file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

How to get string Base64 from an input file .pdf.
i have this function but i dont return the string base64.
the files extencion accept are .pdf
I NEED THE STRING BASE64 IN AN VARIABLE
My code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

Js code

```
var base64 =  getBase64(document.getElementById('files').files[0])
function getBase64(file) {           
    var reader = new FileReader();   
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function () {  
        console.log(reader.result);  
        return(reader.result); //THIS NO RETURN NOTHING. WHY?
    };  
    reader.onerror = function (error) {  
        console.log('Error: ', error);  
    };   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it, it works, you have to add it on the change event, you are calling the getbase64 before anything is there:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/fcgL3dn8/

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("change",getBase64,false);

var _file; 

function getBase64() {     
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();   
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
                reader.onload = function () {  
                    console.log(reader.result); 
                    _file = reader.result; 
                    //don't do the below. It is pointless. Either assign the result to a variable within scope or call a callback
                    //return(reader.result); //THIS NO RETURN NOTHING. WHY?
                };  
                reader.onerror = function (error) {  
                    console.log('Error: ', error);  
                  };   
            }
```

Comment: I cach this.. Index:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at verdetalle (Index:104)  
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick                                                         var file = document.getElementById('files')[0].addEventListener("change", getBase64, false);

Comment: You are catching this in the above code?? Where is the anchor element?

Comment: var file = document.getElementById('files')[0].addEventListener("change", getBase64, false);

Comment: I see what is wrong,you chaged getElementsByTagName to get ElementById. Well you need to understand that getElementById does not return an array. So it means you should do: document.getElementById('files').addEventListener("change", getBase64, false); So there is no [0]

Comment: var file = document.getElementById('files').addEventListener("change", getBase64, false);                                                                                        
            alert(file);//see undefined

Comment: Of course it is undefined! attaching an eventListener returns undefined. You do not know when the change event will occur! Therefore you need to assign a value to your file variable **within** the getBase64 function.

Comment: Failed to return the base64 string, no longer mark error but return nothing

Comment: Bichito, open the console, do you see the message?

Comment: Yes in the console, i see the base64 string.

Comment: i have this....                                                                                          
var file = document.getElementById('files').addEventListener("change", getBase64, false);

Comment: yes than it means it is working. As you can see in the fiddle I commented out the return part. Because returning has no meaning in an event handler because you do not know when it will fire (when will the user upload?). Therefore if you want to store the string somewhere, declare the file outside the getBase64 function like `var file;`

Comment: I updated the answer. When the onload is fired, your base64 will be inside _file variable. So after you upload a file, you can go to console and do console.log(_file);

Comment: excellent, you are the best. Esta funcionando now. thank you brother